# Passing an input to the process created by CreateProcess()

Tags: c++, winapi, process, input

like in the title I was wondering whether is it possible to pass an input by use of redirection operators in CreateProcess(). I tried something like the following:

`CreateProcess(NULL, "%ComSpec% /c c:\\somebatch.bat", NULL, NULL, ...);`

where `somebatch.bat` contained `c:\app.exe < c:\input.txt` and it didn't pass the input, just launched the `app.exe`. On the output it said that:

`c:\working_directory> c:\app.exe < c:\input.txt`

`c:\working_directory>Not enough storage is available to process this command.`

(messing with irpcstack didn't help)

Are you guys aware of any magic trick that would allow me to do what I want without messing with the `hStdInput` pipe, which saying frankly I wanted to avoid. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have done this, but you have to set `hStdInput` member in the [`STARTUPINFO` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passed in as the next to last argument of [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I'm pretty sure that there is no other good way to do this.  Using `hStdInput` is pretty easy, open the file that you want to use as input, set `hStdInput` to the file handle, create the process, and close the handle.

You might be able to open the input file, duplicate the handle into the current processes standard input, and then create the process with `bInheritHandles` set to `TRUE`.  Then your program will simply receive the file contents via `stdin`.  I've never tried this in Windows, but it is common practice on UNIX based platforms.

As for running a batch file, read the comments in the [MSDN entry for `CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I think that you have the arguments messed up.

Comment: to make things more complicated I'm only able to manipulate `lpCommandLine` parameter without any deeply-going modifications. I tried `CreateProcess(NULL, "c:\\somebatch.bat c:\\app.exe c:\\input.txt", ...);` as stated in comments, where `somebatch.bat` content was `%1 < %2` but no success. The only thing that warning with not enough storage wasn't there. Anyway thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you need `CreateProcess`?

The `system` function uses the default shell (so you wouldn't need to put in `%ComSpec%`) which means that redirection would work fine. It's also easier to use and more portable. If you're just going to wait for the process to finish, consider using `system` instead.

Comment: there is no such possibility to use `system()` function